# Links in How to Format when asking a question should point to helpcenter

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking-questions, hyperlinks, help-center

The help section **How to Format** that gets visible when focusing the textbox to enter the body of a question, contains links that point to old sites, that i think are replaced by sites in the new helpcenter.

[formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)  -> should point to [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

[asking help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) -> should point to [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

This applies to the sites for meta as also stackoverflow

Comment: The new formatting help pages don't fully replace the old ones - they provide an intro to formatting, but the old pages provide more detail; that's why they're still linked there.